# How to configure separate compatConfig options per external Vue library with the Vue 3 migration build?

Tags: vue.js, migration, vuejs3, vite

Using the Vue 3 [migration build](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html), it's possible to set a global `compatConfig: { mode: 2 | 3 }` and also separately per component but is it possible to do it per library?

I'm using the [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/vue3) which requires that `compatConfig: { mode: 2 }` is set globally but this breaks many Vue 3 libraries that use the new v-model property names. It's possible to do this on the outer component by wrapping the component object:

```js
<template>
  <SomeComponent />
</template>

<script setup>
import { default as C } = './vue-component'
const SomeComponent = { ...C,  compatConfig: { mode: 3 };
</script>
```

but libraries often use internal components which do not inherit mode 3 that can break their functionality.

Is there a Vite build step I can configure to apply a compatConfig property to modules of my choosing or some other way I can overcome this problem?

Comment: i'm having a similar problem while depending on libraries that are pure v3 without any compat declaration and others that are vue 2 but work with vue-compat. the framework complains about the vue 3 external components using the new v-model syntax but do not have compatConfig set to 3. well, if you are building a vue 3 lib, why would you set that? anyway, the app is breaking.

Comment: this vue 2 to 3 migration is hell on earth since the ecosystem adopted fragmented strategies. vee-validate abandoned its API altogether but if you use it with bootstrap-vue which keeps the vue 2 syntax, things just don't match anymore. gradual migration is hard if not impossible if you depend on things that went opposite ways.

Answer (score 2):

It required some hackery but I found a workaround to this problem using yarn patch and editing the first few lines of the external library to redefine the defineComponent import from vue.

```js
import { defineComponent as defaultDefineComponent } from 'vue';
const defineComponent = obj => defaultDefineComponent({ ...obj, compatConfig: { mode: 3 } });
```

It's not a perfect solution but it does work. I feel as though something similar could be achieved with vite and aliasing but I needed to use yarn patch on this library to wrap a Vue 3 functional component in a call to defineComponent to get around the migration build not applying class attributes to the functional components.